# Informix SQL - What is wrong with this simple stored procedure &| trigger syntax?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, triggers, syntax-error, informix

IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 11.50.FC6

I am trying to execute a simple stored procedure from within an update trigger. Together, they  are used to update a field with the current timestamp when another field in the same row is updated.

Table `sp_test`:

```
id          (serial int, unique, not null, primary key)    
stat        (char(1), not null, default="A")
add_date    (date, not null, default today)
upd_date    (date, null)
```

The stored procedure code is:

```
create procedure upd_row_date_proc (cid int)
update sproc_trig_rec set upd_date = current where id = cid;
end procedure;
```

This executes fine and creates the routine, but the trigger I am trying to implement on updates is not working.

The trigger code is:

```
create trigger upd_row_date_trig
update of stat on sproc_trig_rec
after (execute procedure upd_row_date_proc(id));
```

I've tried a bunch of syntax variations, but cannot get it to work.

I usually get my error on the `(` char of the 3rd line.  Here's the error code:

```
  201: A syntax error has occurred.
Error in line 3
Near character position 0
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong in the syntax of the trigger?  Could this type of updating be defined in the creation of the table, or do I need to accomplish it by doing it the way described above?

Thanks for any help

Comment: It isn't 9.53 - please try: `SELECT DBINFO('version','full') FROM "informix".systables WHERE tabid = 1`.

Comment: IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 11.50.FC6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This finally worked for me

```
create trigger ken_trig
update of stat on sproc_trig_rec
referencing old as ken_pre_upd
for each row (execute procedure ken_proc(ken_pre_upd.id));
```

Comment: Yes - that is one syntax that will do the trick.  It is probably what you were after.  See [CREATE TRIGGER](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v117/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.sqls.doc%2Fids_sqs_0584.htm) and following pages.